# A Lagrange Mulipliers Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

My problem is this: Find the min and max values of $f(x,y)=x^2+3xy+y^2$ on the domain $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. 

I used lagrange multipliers to find that the $y$ coordinate satisfies $f\left(x\right)=8y+(46y^2)/3-16y^3-24y^4=0$ for any critical point $(x,y)$, and $x=2y^2+(2/3)y$
Using Wolfram Alpha, I found that this has roots (aprox.),

$y=-0.97110$

$y=-0.45311$

$y=0.75755$

$y=0$

Wolfram alpha tells me that the function is optimized at the first and third points. However, it is unable to get them in exact form that is not horrendous(multiple radicals involving i). But my professor is expecting an exact answer-and certainly not the exact answer I have. 


Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach that sidesteps the Lagrange multipliers:

Shift the origin to $(1,0)$ so the problem becomes
one of extremising $x^2+xy+y^2+y+2x+1$ subject to $x^2+y^2 = 1$.
Now replace $x,y$ by $\cos t, \sin t$ to reduce to extremising
$(1+\cos t) (2+ \sin t)$, with $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is immediate that the $\min$ is $0$ (take $t= \pi$, for example, noting that
the cost is always non negative).

The $\max$ is a little more painful. The derivative of the cost
is $\cos t +2 \cos^2 t -\sin t -1$, we can look for solutions of
$\cos t +2 \cos^2 t  -1 = \sin t$ by squaring both sides, letting $z=\cos t$ and
utilising the fact that $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t  =1$ to get
$4z^4+4z^3+z^2−2z−3 = 0$, and since we know that $t=\pi$ is a solution,
we can factor $z-\cos \pi$ to get $r(z)=4z^3+z−3 = 0$. We note
that $r$ is strictly increasing and $r(-1) <0, r(1) >0$, hence there
is exactly one root $z^* \in [-1,1]$. A little bisection shows that
$z^* \approx 0.817$ from which we get a $\max$ of
$(1+z)(2+\sqrt{1-z^2}) \approx 4.682$.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange system
$$2x + y = 2\lambda(x-1)$$
$$2y + x = 2\lambda y$$
is linear in $x$,$y$. For $\lambda = 1/2,3/2$ the system has no solution. For $\lambda\ne 1/2,3/2$ the solution is unique: 
$$(x,y) = ((4\lambda^2 - 4\lambda)/(4\lambda^2-8\lambda+3),2\lambda/(4\lambda^2-8\lambda+3))$$
and you must check that the restriction is satisfied. This implies
$$\lambda(4\lambda^3 - 16\lambda^2 + 17\lambda - 6) = 0.$$
This equation has two real solutions: $\lambda = 0,2.576\dots$ and two complex solutions.

Alternative solution: parametrizing $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ as $x = 1 + \cos t$, $y = \sin t$, we have reduced the problem to the study of $g(t) = f(x(t),y(t)) = (1 + \cos t)^2 + (1 + \cos t)\sin t + \sin^2 t$.

Comment: Your answer is not right. It does not yield the correct values for max and min.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard, I will check my calculations tomorrow.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard I suggest you check your calculations.  My numbers are in line with the value of $\lambda$ here.

Comment: I forgot a factor of three in my question-your answers were right, mine wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y,\lambda) = x^2 + y^2 + xy + \lambda (x^2 - 2x + y^2)\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 2(1+\lambda) x + y - 2\lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = x + 2(1+\lambda) y = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial \lambda} = x^2 - 2x + y^2 = 0\\
$

$x,y,\lambda = 0$ is one solution (and is the min)

$2\lambda = -\frac {x+2y}{y}\\ 
2(1+\lambda) = -\frac{x}{y}$

$-\frac {x^2}{y} + y + \frac {x+2y}{y} = 0\\
-x^2 + y^2 + x+2y = 0\\
x^2 + y^2 - 2x = 0\\
2y^2 -x + 2y = 0\\
x = \sqrt {1-y^2}+1\\
2y^2 +2y-\sqrt{1-y^2} -1 = 0\\
2y^2 +2y-1 = \sqrt{1-y^2}\\
4y^4 + 8y^3  - 4y + 1 = 1-y^2\\
4y^4 + 8y^3 +y^2 - 4y = 0\\
y(4y^3 + 8y^2 + y - 4)= 0\\
$

And now we need the cubic formula:

$y = \sqrt[3]{\frac {31}{108}- \sqrt{(\frac {31}{108})^2-(\frac {13}{36})^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac {31}{108}+ \sqrt{(\frac {31}{108})^2-(\frac {13}{36})^3}}-\frac 23\approx 0.57638\\
x = \sqrt{1-y^2}+1 \approx 1.81718\\
f(x,y) = 4.68175$

Comment: Your answer is wrong. $(1.817,0.57638)$ does not lie on the circle, 4.68175 is not the max, and 0 is not the min. Using Mathematica you see that {-1.13128,{x->1.23867,y->-0.9711}} is the actual minimum, and {7.06174,{x->1.65278,y->0.757546}} is the max. The goal was to get these in exact form. I also do not recognize your method of Lagrange multipliers-why aren't you equating gradients?

Comment: Really?  $(1.817-1)^2 + (0.576)^2 \approx  0.332 + 0.668 = 1$ the point does indeed lie on the circle.   $f(1.23867, -0.9711) \approx 1.27$ while $f(0,0) = 0$.  $f(1.23867, -0.9711)$ is not the min.

Comment: I'm sorry! I messed up and forgot a coefficient of three on xy in my question. Your answer looked totally wrong-but it was completely right. I should have double checked before writing a scathing comment.

Comment: Might be better to just avoid the scathing entirely...

Comment: It wasn't exactly scathing. I just said I thought he was wrong, and he wasn't.